# Most efficient way to query over a Join Table in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am having following models and inter-model relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # 1. Serialized constants: 
  # 2. Constants:
  # 3. Associations/Inter-model Relationships

  has_many :ownerships, foreign_key: :reader_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owned_books, class_name: 'Book', through: :ownerships, source: :reader
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # 1. Serialized constants defined below:
  # 2. Constants defined below:
  # 3. Associations/Inter-model Relationships
    has_many :readers, class_name: 'User', through: :ownerships
    has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
...
end
```

that join through :ownerships as following:

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  # 1. Serialized constants defined below:
  # 2. Constants defined below:
  # 3. Associations/Inter-model Relationships
    belongs_to :book
    belongs_to :reader, :class_name => 'User'
  # 4. Attribute accessors
  # 5. Gem configurations e.g.: acts_as_authentic
  # 6. Validations
    validates :reader_id, presence: true
    validates :book_id, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :book_id, :scope => :reader_id
  ...
```

Now to list all the books that the current_user owns, I'm using:

```
@my_books = Book.joins(:readers).where("users.id = ?", current_profile.id)
```

Is this an efficient way to find all books of the current_user? And then I want to list all the users that own a given book so want to be able to query both ways in the most efficient manner.

Comment: Presumably `current_profile` is actually a `User` object?  So why not just do `@my_books = current_profile.books`

Comment: Yes, current_profile is a user object in session. current_profile.books is the list of books that user has authored, not exactly owned. Owned is rather defined through a join table 'ownerships'.

Comment: And yes, it will work in the other direction: `Book.first.readers` should deliver the users back, bu I think you have to define the `ownerships` relationship before the `has_many :readers`

Comment: @japed You meant **current_profile.owned_books** as per relationship defined in the User class?

Comment: Yes, that I did, sorry missed that `owned_books` was the association

Comment: Okay, now that I've tested both: Book.joins(:readers).where("users.id = ?", current_profile.id) returns one book that a user owns, whereas current_profile.owned_books returns a null. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake in my code. The source: declaration in USer class should be:

```
has_many :owned_books, class_name: 'Book', through: :ownerships, source: :book
```

instead of :reader